# Where is the .exe file for a C program in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How come there's is no exefile if you rightclick under you're project and choose Open folder in Windows Explorer and there is no .exe file not under Debug or projectdirectory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple steps that should help to solve the problem.  After opening your project in Visual Studio:

1. Select **Rebuild Solution** from the **Build** menu.  From the **View** menu select **Output** and watch the build output in the window at the bottom of the screen.  You should get a final output something like this, otherwise there was a build error, look through the output window to identify the error:

   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
2. Right click on your project and select **Properties**. In the **General** section of **Linker** look at the **Output File**.  This is the path where the executable should be output. If the path includes macros (i.e. `$(OutDir)`) click the textbox and click the drop-down error that appears to the right and select **Edit**.  In the dialog that appears click the **Macros** button to expand the list of available macros.  This should help you figure out where your executable is and where it is named.

If you just set up a new Visual Studio project, the default path is:

```
$(SolutionDir)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(ProjectName).exe
```

so your path would be something like

```
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestProj\Debug\TestProj.exe
```

Comment: The path was $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe and all the exe was in there, but what it the best workflow, of course it depends but any comment on where to have exes?
BTW thanks!

Comment: That is a typical (default) place to have the exe and should work fine for your project.  $(OutDir) is defined on the **General** tab the **Configuration Properties** under **Output Directory** and defaults to `$(SolutionDir)\$(ConfigurationName)`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to build/debug the project at least ones.

```
D:\yourProjectfolder\yourProject\bin\Debug\yourProject.exe
D:\yourProjectfolder\yourProject\bin\Release\yourProject.exe
```

Comment: No releasefolder...

Answer (score 1):

It should be under your debug or release folder for a c++ project, under the bin folder for a .net project.

Are you sure that the project has been built?

Comment: Yes I've built it the .obj .htm .manifest .manifest.res .manifest .res .manifest .dep .idp and .pdb in that order and no releasefolder

Comment: BTW it's a C program

Comment: @Chris_45: There must have been an linker error probably... look at the output window, are there no errors or warnings?

Comment: Just 1 about the unsafe scanf